# How to configure Swagger-UI to display results as and when received asynchronously instead of waiting for the complete results?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, quarkus, openapi-generator

I am developing a Rest-API service using `Quarkus` and for this, I have added `OpenAPI`  (org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi) annotations to generate `Swagger-UI`. My response can consist of large amounts of data, so I have used the `Multi` (from SmallRye Mutiny) so as to return the response asynchronously during execution.

Everything works perfectly when a small set of data is returned to `Swagger-UI`, The problem arises when a large set of data is returned to Swagger-UI then I believe the Swagger-UI waits for the complete response and the browser stops responding and crashes.

However, when I make a request to the same API endpoint using the `cURL` command, I see that `Mutiny Multi` is working perfectly and returning the response asynchronously and displaying it on the command line, so nothing breaks in `cURL` command and everything works perfectly here, even for very large sets of returned data.

Is there something that I can do so as to avoid the crashing of Swagger-UI, like some additional `open-api` annotation or some custom classes, so as to avoid the Swagger-UI waiting and displaying the results as and when they are received?

**Updated** things I have tried the following based on other answers:

1. I found that some answers have mentioned disabling the `syntaxHighlight` so I tried the same by adding the following lines in my `application.yml` but it is still not working and swagger-ui hangs:

```
quarkus:
  swagger-ui:
    always-include: true
    syntaxHighlight:
      activated: false
  http:
    cors: true
    port: 8080
```

Comment: `syntaxHighlight` has nothing to do with your problem. I'm not sure if Swagger-UI supports async calls. Might as well look at the [OpenAPI Callbacks](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/callbacks/) to see if that helps.

Comment: @DebarghaRoy Thanks a lot for the response, is there anyway to implement the same using the `OpenAPI Annotations` in the `Quarkus` application because I am not creating any yml file, it will be created automatically based on the annotations provided on the Rest API service.

Comment: "large set of data" - how large? There's a known [performance issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3832) with large responses. Plus, as @DebarghaRoy correctly noted, Swagger UI does not support async API calls. If your API is entirely async, you should use [AsyncAPI](https://www.asyncapi.com/) and its related tooling instead of OpenAPI.

Comment: @Helen The amount of events returned by the application depends on user input actually. It can be 1000 events or millions of events. Is there a command that I can use to calculate the size of the sample response via the cURL command for your reference? So currently there is no way to do this using the `OpenAPI` then. All our applications are on `OpenAPI` so switching to `AsyncAPI` would be bit difficult at this time :)

Comment: Perhaps, switching over to Async API would be the best bet but the Java/Spring ecosystem is still evolving around it. But one thing for sure, you should not be using a framework like OpenAPI/AsyncAPI to test with large values. Understand that the primary purpose of them are to provide documentation and a playground sort of thing to explore the APIs, not to be used by user. Input that pushes the response to a large data should be restricted on these documentations.

Comment: @DebarghaRoy I understand now, I will continue to use the `OpenAPI` and ensure that we are using it for documentation/reference purposes, however, users can continue to use the `cURL` command to generate extensive data using the `API endpoints`.